# How to calculate z-score of binomial values for an ab test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-score, ab-test

I ran an ab-test and now I'm trying to calculate the pvalue.  The test and control are binomial and these are the values
[image]

To get the variance, I used the variance formula from here https://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/binomial.aspx

[image]

This gives me the values in orange:
[image]

I should be able to get the z-value by just doing a z-score calculation as show in this link:(https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/two-population-means-with-known-standard-deviations/)
shows that I can calculate the z-score by

[image]

For me, this should be(0.12-0.09)/SQRT(43.8/550+49/450)=.069093. If I look this up (https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/normaldistribution.aspx) this gives a p-value of  .472.

I don't think this is right because if I try a proportion test in Python, I get a different value

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
stat, pval = proportions_ztest(count=np.array([48,56]),
                               nobs=np.array([550, 450]),
                               alternative='two-sided',
                               prop_var=False
                              )
print (stat, pval)
```

I get a t-stat of  1.916 and a p-value of 0.055.

I'm not sure where I have a made a mistake in calculating, can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure you really made a mistake. There are several versions of this test and you may have gotten confused using two versions at once. See my Answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several methods are in common use for testing
$H_0: p_1=p_2$ against $H_a: p_l\ne p_2.$

One method (called 'pooled') uses the null hypothesis $p_1=p_2=p$ to estimate
$\hat p = \frac{x_1+x_2}{n_1+n_2} = \frac{48+56}{550+450}
= \frac{104}{1000} = 0.104$ and then base the (estimated) standard
error of $\hat p_1 - \hat p_2$ (denominator of $Z)$
as $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)(1/n_1+1/n_2)}.$ [See NIST handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm).

Another method is to estimate $Var(\hat p_i), i = 1,2$ separately as $\hat\sigma_i =\hat p_i(1-\hat p_i)/n_i,$ respectively.
Then the (estimated) standard error of $\hat p_1 - \hat p_2$ is
$\sqrt{\hat\sigma_1 + \hat\sigma_2}.$ [See, e.g., Ott & Longnecker: *Intro. to Stat. Meth. and Data Analysis,* Ch 10.] An advantage of this method is that the estimated standard error is also appropriate for making a CI of
$p_1 - p_2.$

Both methods have been used in software implementations of the test for two binomial proportions, sometimes with
various continuity corrections.  Minitab software uses
this method as default, but allows the user to specify
the pooled method.

From a recent release of Minitab, here is output from
the 'separate variances' method, with P-value $0.059.$

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X    N  Sample p
1       48  550  0.087273
2       56  450  0.124444

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.0371717
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0757267, 0.00138324)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
  Z = -1.89  P-Value = 0.059
```

Also, using the 'pooled' method, the P-value is $0.055.$
However, the 95% CI for $p_1 - p_2$ uses the separate variances method, so the CI is exactly the same in both outputs.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X    N  Sample p
1       48  550  0.087273
2       56  450  0.124444

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.0371717
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0757267, 0.00138324)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
  Z = -1.92  P-Value = 0.055
```

Output from the procedure `prop.test` in R, agrees
with the separate variances version of Minitab except
for differences in rounding.

```
prop.test(c(48,56), c(550,450), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(48, 56) out of c(550, 450)
X-squared = 3.6699, df = 1, p-value = 0.0554
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.07572667  0.00138324
 sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.08727273 0.12444444
```

Essentially the same test can be done in R, using a chi-squared test
(`chisq.test`), which uses for input a $2\times 2$ table of successes and failures.

```
TBL = rbind(c(48,56), c(550-48, 450-56)); TBL           
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   48   56
[2,]  502  394

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 3.6699, df = 1, p-value = 0.0554
```

On account of the relatively small counts, some statisticians would use Fisher's exact test, which gives P-value $0.061,$ also failing to reject at the 5% level. [See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).] This P-value for Fisher's exact test is also
shown in Minitab printouts of the pooled and separate
variances methods, but was omitted above.

```
fisher.test(TBL)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.06102
alternative hypothesis: 
 true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4375136 1.0319594
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.6730183
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was so helpful